# Changed the url into https and now can't access site admin

Tags: login, http

I recently did changed in the dashboard the url (http to https) just for test. And yes, the site doesn't work (it is all scramble). Now I can not log into the the WP dashboard to reverse the change. Is there a way to do that from the host server?

Thank yo in advance,
Almir

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 1):

Update your wp-config.php with following lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Where `example.com` your domain

Answer (score 1):

Check the URLs in the wp-options table of your database. Two locations for the actual URL of your site.